# how to stop checkbox from getting checked when confirm box cancel is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When clicking cancel I need the checkbox  to go back to unchecked. But it's getting checked . I tried everything .

```js
function ActivateReg(bID, cID, crID) {
  console.log(bID, cID, crID);
  var result = confirm("Do you really sure?");
  if (result) {
    //$ajax({ ajax call 
  } else {
    $("#chkbox" + bID).prop("checked", false); // not working
  }

  /* else
  {
  $("#chkbox" + bID +cID +crID).prop("checked", false);      // not working 
  }
  */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" onclick="ActivateReg(' + item.as + ',' + item.bs + ',' + item.cs + ')" class="listCheckbox" />
```

Comment: if you click the cancel button, do you want all checkboxes to be unchecked or is the cancel button correspond to only one specific checkbox?

Comment: cancel button correspond to only one specific checkbox .

Comment: Your html for `input` appears to be created server-side or built as a string - it won't work as provided in the question.   `onclick="ActivateReg(' + item.as + ',' + item.bs + ',' + item.cs + ')"` will generate your onclick exactly as that - ie ActiveReg will be called with the strings `" + item.as + "`, `" + item.bs + "` - not as the object/variable replacements.  Check your **rendered html** to ensure the parameters are being provided as you expect them to be.

Comment: Added a console.log to your snippet so that you can see what the parameters are as they are passed.  If this is *not* the case and your actual code (not derived for the question) passes values correctly, then please update the snippet to include the correct `<input>` and related #chkbox+bID so we can see that the IDs match.  See [mcve]

Comment: Please also include the "cancel" button as that seems to be the relevant part of your question *"not working when cancel is clicked"* (but no cancel exist in your question)

Comment: If you were doing event handling _properly_, the jQuery way, instead of adding inline attributes, you could simply prevent the event's default action. https://jsfiddle.net/09r72vk5/

Comment: I need ActivateReg( bID, cID, crID) which is used on server side . how can I apply  preventpreventDefault() in above else part ? .

Comment: can you give us more of your html elements. the ones that has multiple checkboxes with their corresponding "cancel" that you're clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are pointing to correct checkbox with the selector.

Your checkbox id is `chkbox` and you are trying to point some other elements with `"#chkbox" + bID` where `bID` is not needed I suppose.

It works fine without that `bID`  parameter.

```js
function ActivateReg() {
    var result = confirm("Do you really sure?");
    if (result) {
    } else {
        $("#chkbox").prop("checked", false);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input
    type="checkbox"
    id="chkbox"
    onclick="ActivateReg()"
    class="listCheckbox"
  />
```

Comment: I need those bID ,cID, crID  in ajax call. also i implemented only  $("#chkbox").prop("checked", false); but it's still getting checked on confirm box cancel click.

Comment: @tSv Im using the same in my implementation aswell, as you can see that is working fine.

Comment: it's working but it's affecting  rest of the checkboxes as well.

Comment: It worked. I just deleted browser cached etc. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you may include  ***autocomplete='off'*** in your input tag. I had same type of issue which I solved by using this attribute